# Согласование времён в стихотворении

Tags: поэзия

Если каждая строфа представляет собой отдельную картинку, если в каждой из строф время согласовано, но в одной строфе описывается прошедшее время (и написано в прошедшем времени), во второй описывается настоящее время (и написано в настоящем времени), или наоборот, нормально ли это? Справедливо ли мнение критика о том, что всё повествование должно быть выдержано в одном и том же времени? Если справедливо, какое конкретно грамматическое правило нарушено?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общего, внеконтекстного требования выдерживать все строфы или абзацы в одном времени быть не может. Представьте себе первую строфу о том, как хорошо было вчера, и вторую о том, как плохо сегодня, - это вполне нормально:

> Как хороши, как свежи были раки... 
> Хоть и по пять, скупались на ура,
>   
> Огромные - почти что как собаки, 
> Я мог бы взять десяточек вчера.
>
> Сегодня, истязаемый прозреньем, 
> Лишь вижу мелких, хоть они по
>   три. 
> Не в радость мне теперь и воскресенье, 
> Одна печаль - куда
>   ни посмотри.

Проблемы могут быть стилистические у конкретного текста.